# Permission push repo in Github

Tags: github, git-branch, git-svn, git-commit

Can I make permission to push my repo only me? But I don't using private account. How to make permission only me to push all my repository?

Answer (score 0):

When you create new repository, you are already the only one who can actually push to it. (Github authenticates you by open parts of SSH/GPG keys you provide in https://github.com/settings/keys) Other contributors can only create pull requests, that you acccept or not (Or, if you add their credentials directly in repository settings section "Collaborators")

Comment: yes. I already setting SSH key from my leptop to my account github. But I don't know, it's can make my repo not push anotherelse. Are you sure just this? just adding SSH key can make my repo just push only me? @augur's

Comment: Or any else setting up to my repository?  because, before I add SSH key, I try using annonymous email it's can push

Comment: Sure thing. [Pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/be-social/#pull-requests) is the only way to push to other reps, that you are not member of. And incoming pull requests are administered by repository owner.

Comment: @Stfvns without key, you can still push to your repository via https, providing username and password. But still, it can only be done using your, repository owner, account

Comment: @augur Don't confuse committer and author emails in the commits with the ability to push. You can push any commits with any committer or author emails, but only you are able to push.